# NGINX try_files does not find the correct folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've been trying to get a host set up for my personal portfolio site, and I'm just not understanding why NGINX isn't serving up my files as I expect.  My root directory, `/usr/local/var/apps`, holds symlinks to the latest versions of my web apps, including the main site.  I've tried dozens of different configurations, but I think this is the best so far:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name mysupertestsite.com;
    index index.html;
    root /usr/local/var/apps/;

    location / {
        try_files portfolio-page$uri portfolio-page$uri/ $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

I want `http://mysupertestsite.com:8080` to serve up the page under `/usr/local/var/apps/portfolio-page/`, and my web app names in the path to serve up their respective files, i.e. `http://mysupertestsite.com:8080/wikipedia-viewer` should serve up `/usr/local/var/apps/wikipedia-viewer`.  Currently, the apps *do* work.  The main portfolio page *does not*, and I'm getting a `403`.

I'm not married to this configuration or directory structure.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `nginx` URIs begin with `/`. Try using `/portfolio...` on your `try_files` statement.

Comment: Holy crap, that was easy.  Thanks so much!  If you repost that as an answer, this dumb question can get an accepted answer and you can get credit.